# return the image with the lowest views with xml and php?

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to create a weighted banner system for my website.

This is my XML:

```
<banners>
    <images>
        <src>banners/ad_1.png</src>
        <alt>Banner ad 1</alt>
        <views>9</views>
    </images>
    <images>
        <src>banners/ad_2.png</src>
        <alt>Banner ad 2</alt>
        <views>9</views>
    </images>
</banners>
```

I want to display the image with the lowest view. Once I have that image, increment the view to show that the banner has been shown.

I don't want to use simpleXML. All the dom manipulation will directly be using this `$dom` variable:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($file_name);
```

I have been at this for over 3 hours and my code just keeps getting bigger and bigger. I have figured out how to increment it and place it back into the XML file. I just don't know how to pull the image that has the lowest views for display.

Any help, even ideas would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName("images"); //Grab all image nodes
$views = array(); //Set up array for src and viewcount data
foreach($images as $image){ //Loop through all image nodes
   $src = $image->getElementsByTagName("src")->nodeValue; //Get the src
   $views[$src] = $image->getElementsByTagName("views")->nodeValue; //Add the viewcount to the array and use src as the array key
}
asort($views); //Sort the array by viewcount (low->high)
$src = array_keys($views); //Extract keys (or src)

$lowestViews = $views[0]; //Var for lowest number of views
$lowestSrc = $src[0]; //Var for the src of the lowest viewed image
```

I hope that helps! Sorry for mega commenting. Got bored.

Comment: I tried that before, but it would force me to use a static alt text. You actually made me think though, and I got it working with array_multisort. The code a bit long though...

Comment: Fair enough, as long as you've got something which works. Using the dom method is never going to be particularly efficient.

Comment: I hate using it. It's actually for a school project... probably should have included the homework tag. Thanks for your time, he's an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a database for storing your ads so that you can query for this data. With XML, I don't know much of a better way than reading the entire file into an array and then sorting the array at that point, but with MySQL or any other SQL-style database, you can simply run:

```
SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY views LIMIT 1;
```

And that would get you the lowest view count. Updating that view count is easy (and concurrency-safe) too:

```
UPDATE ads SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = <ID>;
```

In short, a relational database lets you *query* your data, whereas an XML file (at least, in its raw form) only lets you *store* it.

Comment: +1 Using a database also makes threading issues far less of a headache - eg page is loaded for user 1. It finds the banner with the lowest views (say 3 views). Before it can write the file, user 2 visits the site and finds the same banner as user 1 (still with 3 views). user 1's page writes the XML with a view value of 4. User 2's page now does the same. Result - Banner shown 5 times, view count is 4. This also doesn't account for issues on the file system (writing the same file at the same time usually results in access violations)

Comment: Fair enough, just a suggestion. My recommendation still stands though; storing this sort of fast-changing data in XML (or any flat-file format like JSON, CSV, whatever) will give you problems in the long run. Edit: Basically, what Basiclife said. (Pun not intended)